# Build step 'Allure Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE

Tags: jenkins, allure

While running tests in `Jenkins` even if all tests finished successfully, I see the following record in Console output:

Build step 'Allure Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE.

> [INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 542.148 s - in TestSuite
>   [INFO] 
>   [INFO] Results:
>   [INFO] 
>   [INFO] Tests run: 2, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0 
>   [INFO] 
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [INFO] Total time: 09:09 min
>   [INFO] Finished at: 2017-11-10T12:20:52+03:00
>   [INFO] Final Memory: 16M/434M
>   [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
>   [PUTUX_1 Smoke Test] $ 
> *.jenkins\tools\ru.yandex.qatools.allure.jenkins.tools.AllureCommandlineInstallation\allure\bin\allure.bat generate "*\target\allure-results" -c -o *\allure-report" 
>   Report successfully generated to *.jenkins\workspace\PUTUX_1 Smoke Test\allure-report
>   Allure report was successfully generated.
>   Creating artifact for the build.    
>   Artifact was added to the build.
>   Build step 'Allure Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE
>   Finished: UNSTABLE

What is the reason for such a strange behavior?

Comment: any failures in the allure report ?

Answer (score 0):

For me it helped to delete old results from folder with allure-results, because it mapped in report results from older tests that were broken

Comment: Isn't the allure plugin supposed to clean up the directory before creating new results in the existing directory