# Jenkins Allure marking the build as unstable

Tags: python, jenkins, allure

Jenkins Allure marking the build as unstable though everything ran successfully. Is this because of the % of success. I have 1 out of 4 failed test.

```
Allure report was successfully generated.
Creating artifact for the build.
Artifact was added to the build.
Build step 'Allure Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE
Finished: UNSTABLE
```

Same questions asked here:
[Build step 'Allure Report' changed build result to UNSTABLE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47221524/build-step-allure-report-changed-build-result-to-unstable)

Answer (score 0):

Recreated the job, this error went away.